# HTML bug, Image not displaying on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a website for my friend's Graphic Design company.

I keep getting this bug where the `<img>` and `<video>` just displays my container without any Images/Video in it just a black box. Not even my alt's?? I've never had this happen before.

I do have quite a lot of stuff going on in my stylesheet; including beizer transformations on the container, would that be a problem as it was working, but I changed the image dimensions.

My question is, how do I debug this/ how do I get it to just display my photos in my container.

Edit: I'm 2nd year CompSci but am new to HTML/CSS

My image and mp4 is in the same directory of my index.html in the img and vids folder:

- website/img/Sunburnt.jpg
- website/vids/statuspr.mp4
- website/index.html

  ```
     <div class="col project-wrap">
          <div class="col__item project">
              <div class="project__count"><span class="project__count-current reveal">02</span><span class="project__count-total reveal">/ 28</span></div>
              <a class="project__image noselect" target="_blank" href="#">
                  <div class="project__image-container plane plane--media">
                      <!-- The preferred img, mp4s -->
                      <img src="/img/Sunburnt.jpg" alt="Sunburnt Breakfast Rave" />
                      <video src="vids/statuspr.mp4" muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="preload"></video>
                  </div>

              </a>
              <div class="project__meta">
                  <h3 class="project__meta-title plane">Canberra Rave Scene</h3>
                  <div class="project__meta-tags">
                      <div class="reveal"><span>Social Media</span><span>Entertainment</span><span>Rave</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="reveal"><span>Visuals</span><span>DJ</span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  ```

Comment: Debug it using the Elements tab in Developer Tools. There's probably something in your HTML that's causing it not to parse as you expect, so you can see how it's being parsed there.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Without the CSS it's hard to tell if that's the problem; you can use the stack overflow snippet tool to paste it all in. The img path starts with a slash so that's going to go to the root of that domain no matter where it is in any sub directory.

Comment: no error message, but in the dev tools on the website the src="undefined". I can't see why that would be?

Comment: Charlie, I originally had data-src's instead of src's for  the image and videos; but that is no longer possible. Is it just fine to switch between the two? Maybe that is causing the errors? they are seemingly undefined directory locations, but I can't see why??

Answer (score 0):

I cant comment so i try as an answer even though its not 100% clear:
Just looking at your code:

you use a /  before the img folder only with the image. 
If you're not looking at the file from a server, this will give a 404..

debug using F12, and look at network errors or console errors

Comment: I have an 'a' tag there because I want my image - which after hovering over for 2 sec transformes into a video - to be clickable. Also the visual studio debugger for chrome is difficult to understand, do you know any good tutorials?

Comment: i mean your src= starts with a '/' , only with the image tag, which is not working for you.

You should open the page in Chrome, and press F12 on your keyboard.  It will open the dev tools. Click on 'Console' tab (or Network) and look for errors there.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix this by creating a new container (project__image-container2) which used a less intricate implementation of CSS in my stylesheet.

> I also changed up my src from data-src and just including my images and videos in my project. The combination of these two solutions did solve my problem - that I could not display images and videos withing these containers - however, my website now loads said videos and images quite slowly. However that is something I can try and fix later.

```
<!-- Project 1: Sunburnt Breakfast -->
    <div class="section section--work" data-label="Project 01">
        <div class="col project-wrap">
            <div class="col__item project">
                <div class="project__count"> <span class="project__count-current reveal">02</span><span class="project__count-total reveal">/ 28</span></div>
                <a class="project__image noselect" target="_blank" href="website-I-don't-want-the-world-to-know-about">
                    <div class="project__image-container2 plane">

                        <video src="vids/visualsTrim.mp4" muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="preload"></video>
                        <noscript>
                        <video src="vids/visualsTrim.mp4" muted="muted" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="preload"></video>
                    </noscript>
                    </div>

                </a>
                <div class="project__meta">
                    <h3 class="project__meta-title plane">Canberra Rave Scene</h3>
                    <div class="project__meta-tags">
                        <div class="reveal"><span>Social Media</span><span>Entertainment</span><span>Rave</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="reveal"><span>Visuals</span><span>DJ</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="section__nav section__nav--left noselect clickable"><span class="text--giant text--bold"><span>Back</span></span></button>
        <button class="section__nav section__nav--right noselect clickable"><span class="text--giant text--bold"><span>Next</span></span></button>
    </div>
```

I hope that this helps anyone facing this niche problem out there. DM me or comment and I will try to help you through it if you are struggling with this issue too.

Thank you to everyone who helped me get here. Love my stackoverflow community !!! Yall the best xx